# How to display video from ALAsset to UICollectionview ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, alassetslibrary

I tried below code to get all videos from photo library by using `ALAsset`. For now, i want to display all videos to a `UICollectionview` but it doesn't seem to display anything. Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

-ViewDidLoad() : get all videos from Photo Library

```
allVideos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     if (group)
     {
         [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
          {
              if (asset)
              {
                  dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                  ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                  NSString *uti = [defaultRepresentation UTI];
                  NSURL  *videoURL = [[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:uti];
                  NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video %d", arc4random()%100];
                  UIImage *image = [self imageFromVideoURL:videoURL];
                  [dic setValue:image forKey:@"image"];
                  [dic setValue:title forKey:@"name"];
                  [dic setValue:videoURL forKey:@"url"];
                  [allVideos addObject:dic];
                  [_collectionView reloadData];
              }
          }];
     }
 }
 failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
```

-imageFromVideoURL():

```
    - (UIImage *)imageFromVideoURL:(NSURL*)videoURL
{
    // result
    UIImage *image = nil;

    // AVAssetImageGenerator
    AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];;
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    // calc midpoint time of video
    Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([asset duration]);
    CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600);

    // get the image from
    NSError *error = nil;
    CMTime actualTime;
    CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

    if (halfWayImage != NULL)
    {
        // CGImage to UIImage
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
        [dic setValue:image forKey:@"name"];
         NSLog(@"Values of dictionary==>%@", dic);
        NSLog(@"Videos Are:%@",videoURL);
        CGImageRelease(halfWayImage);
    }
    return image;
}
```

Start to display all thumbnails of video to UICollectionView:

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return allVideos.count;
}




 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"allvideo %@", allVideos);
        ALAsset *alasset = [allVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this Line:-

```
              [allVideos addObject:dic];
```

With

```
              [allVideos addObject: asset];
```

And in this method:-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"allvideo %@", allVideos);
    ALAsset *alasset = [allVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:alasset.thumbnail];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all take the code `[_collectionView reloadData]` out of the ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock (the block you passed to `-enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:`) as it'll call the `-reloadData` for all the AVAssets found.

There is a sample app "[MyImagePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135)" available from apple which does the exact thing you want to do. You can study the working from there.

Comment: thanks, but if ake the code [_collectionView reloadData] out of the ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock, uicollectionview does not show thumbnailof video.

Comment: In my app I have written `-reloadData` after the enumeration block and I find it executes synchronously after the block. Also if you check the app on the provided link, apple have called the enumeration block in `-viewWillAppear` and `-reloadData` in `-viewDidAppear`

Comment: Thanks. I did it success but now i'm stuck in getting size of video. Can you tell me how to get size of video?

Comment: You can obtain a [ALAssetRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from an [ALAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAsset/defaultRepresentation) and there you can find different options to get size, dimensions etc.

Comment: Yes, thanks. One more thing: Do you know how to remove overlay image when deselect in uicollectionview? I added overlay image when select, now i'm stuck in When scrolling, my cell auto refresh. I dont want it auto refresh.