# Get Camera Roll photos to a Custom Collection View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an Custom Collection View with Cells. Here is my CollectionView code.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

I want to get images from Camera Roll & display in these cells. How can I get Camera Roll images to view in this Cell? Should I use an array to store names of the images & then show them in the Cell?
Can anyone please give me a solution with a code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035337/how-to-display-video-from-alasset-to-uicollectionview-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Albums and Photo/video assets using `<AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` framework :

```
-(void)getAlbum
{
   library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock listGroupBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

        if (group)
       {
            [_albumsArray addObject:group];
        } else {
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    };

   [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:listGroupBlock failureBlock:failureBlock]
}
```

While selecting album you will get photos/video by below method

```
-(void)getAssets
{
    ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset * result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

        if (result)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    };

    [_assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];

    [_assetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerationBlock];
}
```

Please refer this [link](https://github.com/iosnatarajan/photolibrary) for more info and example with table view. Alos you can replace table view with your `UICollectionView`

Thanks!