# How to add camera capture images in view in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

i want add the camera capture images in one view. if i take many photo means all the photos means that photo should add in the view. we can scroll and see the all images in the view.how to do it? i am new for iOS..

Comment: Can you explain it clearly.It is better to upload sample wireframe what you need @saravanaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `UIImagePickerController`, it will show all the images and videos in a separate view

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

if you want get the images into your custom view follow this link once [Get camera roll images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575568/get-camera-roll-photos-to-a-custom-collection-view)